# Javascript - Repeated use of a function without it removing previous instances?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I repeat the output of a function, without it affecting previous instances outputs of the function?

For some context:

I am creating a text editor and have created a "link-maker" which creates an relative href link.

However, when I append the link to the text area content, the link displays perfectly for the first instance. Yet, if I repeat that function to add another relative link, it removes the html wrapping the first link appended.

I have tried changing the text output of the link to getElementByClassName, as I thought that the ID would only be best used for a sole function which would not need to be repeated. Where as by using the class it allows for more general use.

Some code for example:

```
<textarea name="textarea"  class="txtarea" id="textarea" style="display: none; font-family: Arial;"></textarea>

  <iframe name="editor" id="editor" style="width:824; height: 400; font-family: Arial;"></iframe>
```

```js
function bcmllink() {
      var logicalid = document.getElementById("logicalid");
      var txtinput = document.getElementById("txtinput");
      var txtOutput = document.getElementById("txtOutput");
      var name = logicalid.value;
      txtOutput.value = "\x3ca href\x3d\x22\x23\x22 bcmltype\x3d\x22link\x22 logicalid\x3d\x22" + logicalid.value + "\x22\x3e" + txtinput.value + "\x3c\x2fa\x3e"
      } 
   

function appendtotext() {
 var myTextArea = $('.txtarea');
myTextArea.val(editor.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = editor.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].
  textContent + txtOutput.value + "&nbsp;")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="textarea"  class="txtarea" id="textarea" style="display: none; font-family: Arial;"></textarea>

  <iframe name="editor" id="editor" style="width:824; height: 400; font-family: Arial;"></iframe>

    <div id="bcml">
  <h3>BCML Links</h3>
  <form action="">
    <fieldset class="bcml_links">
      <label>Enter your logical id</label><input type="number" id="logicalid" class="left5"/><br><br>
      <label>Enter your text</label><input type="text" id="txtinput" class="left5"/><input class="left5" type="button" value="Generate" onClick="bcmllink()" /><br><br>
      <input type="text" style="width : 600;" id="txtOutput" /><br><br>
      <b>Copy and paste this text into your source view</b>
      <input type="button" value="append" onClick="appendtotext()"/>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the answer to what I was looking for:

```
function appendtotext() {
var myTextArea = $('.txtarea');myTextArea.val(editor.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = editor.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].
    innerHTML + txtOutput.value + "&nbsp;")}
```

The issue was that I was previously using textContent on the last line (where innerHTML now sits). This meant that with each instance of the function being used, it was removing the surrounding html tags and placing in only the text content.

See here for further information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using lists instead of textarea. Im currently using this for a chatapp im creating and it doesnt remove the previous messages when i recieve a new one.

Comment: Thanks Mathias, but as I will need to export the source view of this text for implementation as an article, lists do not provid eit in the best format.

Answer (score 0):

You are already importing jquery. Why not make use of its `.text()` function?

```
$('textarea#textarea').text("<a href='ok'>Click here</a>");
```

Note, that you will not have to worry about formatting HTML or escaping characters.

If you want to append to a previously filled textarea: you would do something like:

```
var old_text = $('textarea#textarea').text();

$('textarea#textarea').text(old_text + "<a href='ok'>Click here</a>");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ahmad! Correct me if I'm wrong - would .val() not be a better option as .text() isn't suggested to work for form elements? _form elements as in input, select, or in my case text area_ 
Or is .text() just a function I haven't explored fully?

Comment: @Dandan using .text() will take care of escaping html. Using .val() will not